# Adding hover drop-down menu to my navigation bar that is a series of sliced IMAGES

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm currently trying to find the best way to add a drop-down menu that appears upon hover over my navigation bar.  A few things to note:

1) I designed my own navigational header in Photoshop and spliced the images.  My entire header will consist of nothing but .jpegs and I need to find a way to add a drop down menu when I hover over one of my "buttons" or "images".

2) This will be used for a business so it needs to be compatible with all browsers to a reasonable version date.  I.E. included.

Please see my code below:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>DropDown Design2</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<!-- ImageReady Styles (DropDown Design2.psd) -->
<style type="text/css">
<!--

#Table_01 {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    width:864px;
    height:216px;
}

#DropDown-Design2-01 {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    width:139px;
    height:50px;
}

#DropDown-Design2-02 {
    position:absolute;
    left:139px;
    top:0px;
    width:131px;
    height:50px;
}
-->
</style>
<!-- End ImageReady Styles -->
</head>






<body style="background-color:#FFFFFF; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px;">
<!-- ImageReady Slices (DropDown Design2.psd) -->
<div id="Table_01">
    <div id="DropDown-Design2-01">
        <img src="images/DropDown-Design2_01.jpg" width="139" height="50" alt="">
    </div>
    <div id="DropDown-Design2-02">
      <img src="images/DropDown-Design2_02.jpg" width="131" height="50" alt=""
    </div>
    <div id="DropDown-Design2-03">
        <img src="images/DropDown-Design2_03.jpg" width="22" height="50" alt="">
    </div>
    <div id="DropDown-Design2-04">
        <img src="images/DropDown-Design2_04.jpg" width="133" height="50" alt="">
    </div>
    <div id="DropDown-Design2-05">
        <img src="images/DropDown-Design2_05.jpg" width="20" height="50" alt="">
    </div>
    <div id="DropDown-Design2-06">
        <img src="images/DropDown-Design2_06.jpg" width="134" height="50" alt="">
    </div>
    <div id="DropDown-Design2-07">
        <img src="images/DropDown-Design2_07.jpg" width="18" height="50" alt="">
    </div>
    <div id="DropDown-Design2-08">
        <img src="images/DropDown-Design2_08.jpg" width="1" height="50" alt="">
    </div>
    <div id="DropDown-Design2-09">
        <img src="images/DropDown-Design2_09.jpg" width="132" height="50" alt="">
    </div>
    <div id="DropDown-Design2-10">
        <img src="images/DropDown-Design2_10.jpg" width="134" height="50" alt="">
    </div>
    <div id="DropDown-Design2-11">
        <img src="images/DropDown-Design2_11.jpg" width="347" height="166" alt="">
    </div>
    <div id="DropDown-Design2-12">
        <img src="images/DropDown-Design2_12.jpg" width="103" height="142" alt="">
    </div>
    <div id="DropDown-Design2-13">
        <img src="images/DropDown-Design2_13.jpg" width="223" height="166" alt="">
    </div>
    <div id="DropDown-Design2-14">
        <img src="images/DropDown-Design2_14.jpg" width="191" height="166" alt="">
    </div>
    <div id="DropDown-Design2-15">
        <img src="images/DropDown-Design2_15.jpg" width="103" height="24" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
<!-- End ImageReady Slices -->
</body>
</html>
```

I understand not much coding has been done in terms of the drop down but currently these images are all set up to form a header with a navigation bar at the very top.  At the very least I would greatly appreciate it if someone could link me to a tutorial consisting of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Thank you!

Comment: Include your code inside your post, don't link to pastebin. Use the built-in code formatting.

Comment: Apologies, what's the best way to do that?  My current code has about 200 lines.. do I have to 4 space each line manually?

Comment: So firstly, I'd try to reduce the size of your example just a bit if you can. If every part of it is relevant, include it, but if the problem can be demonstrated with only portions of the code, do that. As for actually indenting it, if you paste it into the editor, then select it, then click the "Code" button in the toolbar, it will indent it for you. You can also indent it in an editor (using whatever shortcuts that editor supports) and then paste it in indented.

Comment: Okay, I did that for you.  It includes both the CSS and HTML.  The CSS is pretty much the same for each spliced images, minus the positioning and height/width px, etc.